# How to calculate price based on line item custom attributes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, shopify, shopify-api

I am using the shopify-buy sdk to create a react app as the web app to my shopify store using the storefront api. In my store, I have a line item which contains custom attributes: height and width. I would like to use the height and width to calculate the price for that line item.

Here is my code to add a line item:

```js
const addItemToCheckout = async (variantId: string, quantity: string, height: string, width: string) => {
    const lineItemsToAdd = [
      {
        variantId,
        quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10),
        customAttributes: [{ height, width }]
      }
    ];

    try {
      const newCheckout = await client.checkout.addLineItems(
        checkout.id,
        lineItemsToAdd
      );
      setCheckout(newCheckout);

      openCart();
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(`Failed to add item with id '${variantId}' to cart`);
      console.error(err);

      setError(err);
    }
  };
```

The issue is, by default, the price of the lineitem is calculated by simply multiplying the line item quantity by the product price, is it possible to override the way the price is calculated so that it is the height multiplied by width multiplied by quantity multiplied by the product price?

Comment: You should include some example code as a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: voted to reopen as it is clearer now. You'll need a stray Shopify API / SDK subject matter expert, though, as it seems to be related to how a specific API works (I noticed it because it was tagged TypeScript)